# Trying to write gradient creator javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gradient

Edit: I finally come up with a bit different, but working version. Leaving link here for anyone who may need it in the future: https://jsfiddle.net/qmgob1d5/27/

---

I'm trying to make a gradient creator, that runs across 16 boxes. (which color values later going to be sent trough POST for server)

I got it working, to a point, Where I can select first and last color and make gradient. However, i  couldn't figure out for the life of me, how to add more gradient points. eg: change color of any box and calculate gradient values between 3..4..5..etc points. like on this site: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Here is fiddle set up with code: https://jsfiddle.net/qmgob1d5/11/

```
//Fill the gradient array with gray color.
var PaletteColors = Array.apply(null, Array(16)).map(function () { return {red:128, green:128, blue:128}; });

var ActiveBox = 0;
MakeGradient(); //run gradient maker at start

//Remove marker
$('.ColorPreview').contextmenu(function() {
  $('#' +  $(this).attr('id') ).css('border-bottom','0px');
return false
});

//Add marker and snap sliders to rgb values.
$('.ColorPreview').on('click',function() {

    ActiveBox = $(this).attr('id');
    ActiveBox = Number(ActiveBox.split('_')[1]);
  $('#Color_' + ActiveBox).css('border-bottom','6px solid');

    $('#red').val( PaletteColors[ActiveBox].red );
        $('#green').val( PaletteColors[ActiveBox].green );
        $('#blue').val( PaletteColors[ActiveBox].blue );
});

//Read values from sldier write them to PaletteColors array.
$('.Paletteslider').on('change mousemove',function() {
    var red = ($('#red').val());
    var green = ($('#green').val());
    var blue = ($('#blue').val());

        PaletteColors[ActiveBox].red = Number(red);
        PaletteColors[ActiveBox].green = Number(green);
        PaletteColors[ActiveBox].blue = Number(blue);
    MakeGradient();
});

//Draw gradient based on PaletteColors array.
function MakeGradient() {
var FirstColor = PaletteColors[0];
var SecondColor = PaletteColors[15];
var end = 15;
var Count = 1/end;

        for (i = 0; i <= end; i++ ) {

        var Step = Count * i;
        var CurrentRed = SecondColor.red * Step + FirstColor.red * (1 - Step);
        var CurrentGreen = SecondColor.green * Step + FirstColor.green * (1 - Step);
        var CurrentBlue = SecondColor.blue * Step + FirstColor.blue * (1 - Step);

        PaletteColors[i].red = CurrentRed; PaletteColors[i].green = CurrentGreen; PaletteColors[i].blue = CurrentBlue;

    $('#Color_' + i ).css('background-color','rgb('+ Math.round(CurrentRed) +','+  Math.round(CurrentGreen) + ',' + Math.round(CurrentBlue) +')');
        }
 }
```

any help or direction is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the functionality you seek by adding trackers to the items in the `PaletteColors` array (`id` and `edited` properties), modifying the functionality of `makeGradient`, and adding a corresponding modification of `edited` to the `Paletteslider` event.

In order for additional markers to be added, you find a way to assess which colors have been modified or are the first/last colors in `PaletteColors`. I chose to filter an array on conditions if `edited` is true or the element is the first/last in array. From there, you can assign the values of `FirstColor` and `SecondColor` to the first and second color of `PaletteColors`, respectively.

To change the value of the  `FirstColor` and `SecondColor`: inside the `for` loop, check if the id isn't the first or last element and if the `SecondColor` id equals `i`, and change the values of `FirstColor`/`SecondColor` if so. When assigning the colors to the various elements and creating the gradient, you can check whether `i` is equal to the `FirstColor` or `SecondColor` `id` property. If it is, use the current color of `FirstColor` or `SecondColor` gradient to allow it to show up, otherwise apply your transitional formula. See code snippet below for full working example.

```js
//Fill the gradient array with gray color.
var PaletteColors = Array.apply(null, Array(16)).map(function(item, i) {
    return { id: i, color: { red: 128, green: 128, blue: 128 }, edited: false }; });

var ActiveBox = 0;
MakeGradient(); //run gradient maker at start

//Remove marker
$('.ColorPreview').contextmenu(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).css('border-bottom', '0px');
    return false
});

//Add marker and snap sliders to rgb values.
$('.ColorPreview').on('click', function() {
    ActiveBox = Number($(this).data('col'));

    $('#Color_' + ActiveBox).css('border-bottom', '6px solid');

    $('#red').val(PaletteColors[ActiveBox].color.red);
    $('#green').val(PaletteColors[ActiveBox].color.green);
    $('#blue').val(PaletteColors[ActiveBox].color.blue);
    
    var a = PaletteColors.filter(function(col, i) {
        return col.edited || i === 0 || i === 15;
    }).map(function(item, i) {
        item.count = i;
        return item;
    });

});

//Read values from sldier write them to PaletteColors array.
$('.Paletteslider').on('change mousemove', function() {
    var red = Number($('#red').val());
    var green = Number($('#green').val());
    var blue = Number($('#blue').val());
    
    if (!PaletteColors[ActiveBox].edited) {
        PaletteColors[ActiveBox].edited = true;
    }
    PaletteColors[ActiveBox].color.red = red;
    PaletteColors[ActiveBox].color.green = green;
    PaletteColors[ActiveBox].color.blue = blue;
    MakeGradient();
});


//Draw gradient based on PaletteColors array.
function MakeGradient() {
    var colors = PaletteColors.filter(function(col, i) {
        return col.edited || i === 0 || i === 15;
    }).map(function(item, i) {
        item.count = i;
        return item;
    });

    var FirstColor = colors[0];
    var SecondColor = colors[1];
    var end = 15;
    var Count = 1 / end;

    for (i = 0; i <= end; i++) {
        if (colors.length > 2 && i !== 0 && i !== 15 && SecondColor.id === i) {
            FirstColor = SecondColor;
            SecondColor = colors[SecondColor.count + 1];
        }
     

        var Step = Count * i;
        var Current = {};
        var str;
        var match = FirstColor.id === i || SecondColor.id === i ? FirstColor.id === i ? 1 : 2 : false;
        if (match) {
        Current = match === 1 ? FirstColor.color : SecondColor.color;
        } else {
        Current.red = Math.round(SecondColor.color.red * Step + FirstColor.color.red * (1 - Step));
        Current.green = Math.round(SecondColor.color.green * Step + FirstColor.color.green * (1 - Step));
        Current.blue = Math.round(SecondColor.color.blue * Step + FirstColor.color.blue * (1 - Step));
         }
  
        PaletteColors[i].color.red = Current.red > 255 ? 255 : Current.red;
        PaletteColors[i].color.green = Current.green > 255 ? 255 : Current.green;
        PaletteColors[i].color.blue = Current.blue > 255 ? 255 : Current.blue;
        str = 'rgb(' + [Current.red, Current.blue, Current.green].join(',') + ')';
        $('#Color_' + i).css('background-color', str);

    }
}
```

```css
body, html{
  background: #222222;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 color:white;
 }

.ColorPreview {
background: rgb(0,0,0); 
float: left;
height: 5em;
width: 6.25%;
border-bottom: 0px solid;
border-color: lightgrey;
}

#Color_0 {border-bottom: 0px solid;}
#Color_1 {border-bottom: 0px solid;}
#Color_2 {border-bottom: 0px solid;}
#Color_3 {border-bottom: 0px solid;}
#Color_4 {border-bottom: 0px solid;}
#Color_5 {border-bottom: 0px solid;}
#Color_6 {border-bottom: 0px solid;}
#Color_7 {border-bottom: 0px solid;}
#Color_8 {border-bottom: 0px solid;}
#Color_9 {border-bottom: 0px solid;}
#Color_10 {border-bottom: 0px solid;}
#Color_11 {border-bottom: 0px solid;}
#Color_12 {border-bottom: 0px solid;}
#Color_13 {border-bottom: 0px solid;}
#Color_14 {border-bottom: 0px solid;}
#Color_15 {border-bottom: 0px solid;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="PreviewTable" >
<div class="ColorPreview" id="Color_0" data-col="0">Color0</div>
<div class="ColorPreview" id="Color_1" data-col="1">Color1</div>
<div class="ColorPreview" id="Color_2" data-col="2">Color2</div>
<div class="ColorPreview" id="Color_3" data-col="3">Color3</div>
<div class="ColorPreview" id="Color_4" data-col="4">Color4</div>
<div class="ColorPreview" id="Color_5" data-col="5">Color5</div>
<div class="ColorPreview" id="Color_6" data-col="6">Color6</div>
<div class="ColorPreview" id="Color_7" data-col="7">Color7</div>
<div class="ColorPreview" id="Color_8" data-col="8">Color8</div>
<div class="ColorPreview" id="Color_9" data-col="9">Color9</div>
<div class="ColorPreview" id="Color_10" data-col="10">Color10</div>
<div class="ColorPreview" id="Color_11" data-col="11">Color11</div>
<div class="ColorPreview" id="Color_12" data-col="12">Color12</div>
<div class="ColorPreview" id="Color_13" data-col="13">Color13</div>
<div class="ColorPreview" id="Color_14" data-col="14">Color14</div>
<div class="ColorPreview" id="Color_15" data-col="15">Color15</div>
</div>
<div>
&nbsp;
</div>
<div>
<p>
right click to remove marker
</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>red</p>
<span id="spanHueIndex"></span>
<p> <input class="slider Paletteslider" id="red" type="range" step="1" min="0" max="255" value="0" /></p>
<p>green</p>
<span id="spanSaturationIndex"></span>
<p> <input class="slider Paletteslider" id="green" type="range" step="1" min="0" max="255" value="0" /></p>
<p>blue</p>
<span id="spanLightnessIndex"></span>
<p> <input class="slider Paletteslider" id="blue" type="range" step="1" min="0" max="255" value="0" /></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, I worked on it a bit more. Decided to go with a different approach, and simply let user decide range. and use 2 sliders (tho maybe one could be enough) also makes the code simpler.
  
But now, I've encountered a strange behavior. I want to add a copy color function via right click. But, if i copy the colors with right click, the second set of rgb slider wont update the second color anymore. No idea why. Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/qmgob1d5/23/

Comment: Found the problem, apparently, If both elements are an object, somethings goes wrong if i try to do this: `PaletteColors[i] = PaletteColors[CopyBox]` Strangely enough there are no errors, but definitely not working right. however: replacing that code with: `PaletteColors[i].red = PaletteColors[CopyBox].red` works  fine